# R-Selenium, How to overcome Noelement Exception and continue the Execution

Tags: r, selenium, xpath

I am newbie to R-selenium web driver. I have task to accomplish, I have to download all Excel file from the following website.http://lus.dacnet.nic.in/dt_lus.aspx

I am using R-Selenium Webdriver to automate the process. Attached is the code snippet.

```
library(XML)
library(RSelenium)
library(dplyr)
library(magrittr)

Start Selenium Server ------------------------------------------------------

checkForServer()
startServer()
remDrv <- remoteDriver()
remDrv$open()

# Simulate browser session and fill out form ------------------------------

remDrv$navigate('http://lus.dacnet.nic.in/dt_lus.aspx')

#Select Year

remDrv$findElement(using = "xpath", 
               "//select[@name = 'DropDownList2']/option[@value = '1999-00']")$clickElement()

#Select Format

remDrv$findElement(using = "xpath", 
               "//select[@name = 'DropDownList3']/option[@value =  '2']")$clickElement()

#Select Element

district_IDs <- remDrv$findElements(using = "xpath",
                            "//select[@name = 'DropDownList1']/option") %>%
  lapply(function(x){x$getElementAttribute('value')}) %>% 
  unlist

district_names <- remDrv$findElements(using = "xpath",
                                "//select[@name = 'DropDownList1']/option")       %>%
 lapply(function(x){x$getElementText()}) %>% 
  unlist

# Retreive and Download

for (i in seq_along(district_IDs)) {

remDrv$findElement(using = "xpath",
                 paste0("//select[@name = 'DropDownList1']/option[@value =   ", 
                   "'", district_IDs[i], "']"))$clickElement()

#1.Total Area and Classification of Area  
  webElem <- remDrv$findElement(using = "xpath", 
               "//td[@class = 'TreeView1_2 TreeView1_8']/a[@id =  'TreeView1t2']")$clickElement()
```

The execution stops here at 8th state and returns Noelement Exception and terminates

```
#2.1 Sourcewise Area Irrigated                 
webElem2 <- remDrv$findElement(using = "xpath", 
               "//td[@class = 'TreeView1_2 TreeView1_8']/a[@id =  'TreeView1t4']")$clickElement()
Sys.sleep(10)

remDrv$goBack()
}   
remDrv$quit()
remDrv$closeServer()
```

The code works for 8 states and i can download excel files automatically but however when it reaches to 8th State(Dadranagarahavelli) It returns Elementnotfound Exception.

Error Message:-

```
Summary: NoSuchElement
Detail: An element could not be located on the page using the given   search parameters.
class: org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!!!

Comment: Did you try running from that 8th state to say 9th state ( i=8 & 9)? Does it give an error?

Comment: Thanks for your valuable reply. Yes, i can download individual State but in 'for loop' i did not specify state id.Coz, i want all state Excel files needs to be download.

Comment: Did you try running the code "by hand" for i=8?

Comment: Well, I figured out the way. Basically the tag element  "id" was giving an error. Instead of typing manually a[@id =  'TreeView1t4']. I just copy pasted. And i increased the sleep time. After doing this edits i didn't find any error. I can download files for all the states and for all time periods.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions!@user227710 and @Dason